# Why does my Mac always crash when I enable `ask for password after screensaver ended`?

Tags: macos, mac, crash, screensaver, black-screen-of-death

I have enabled these two things:

- Placing the mouse-pointer in the bottom-left corner of any display makes the screensaver appear
- After the screensaver or stand-by has ended, ask for password

However, this combination always leads to this (Black Screen of Death) after entering the screensaver with the bottom-left corner:

[image: please fix your slow internet connection so you can load this image]

Here are my system specs:

## Hardware Overview:

```
  Model Name:   iMac
  Model Identifier: iMac9,1
  Processor Name:   Intel Core 2 Duo
  Processor Speed:  2,66 GHz
  Number Of Processors: 1
  Total Number Of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache: 6 MB
  Memory:   2 GB
  Bus Speed:    1,07 GHz
  Boot ROM Version: IM91.008D.B08
  SMC Version (system): 1.44f0
  Serial Number (system):   W89171JF0TF
  Hardware UUID:    323A90F0-8A2F-5057-B501-2087489E0DFF
```

## System Software Overview:

```
  System Version:   Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573)
  Kernel Version:   Darwin 10.3.0
  Boot Volume:  Macintosh HD
  Boot Mode:    Normal
  Computer Name:    YOU SHOULD NOT KNOW THIS
  User Name:    YOU SHOULD NOT KNOW THIS
  Secure Virtual Memory:    Not Enabled
  64-bit Kernel and Extensions: No
  Time since boot:  11:46
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: Panic logs would be more useful than your system stats.

Answer (score 6):

That kind of crash is called a *kernel panic*. The log of the kernel panic is saved in NVRAM at the time of the panic (if possible), and written out to a file in `/Library/Logs/PanicReporter/` at the next boot.  If you post the contents of your panic log, people can possibly glean details of exactly what part of your kernel is panicking.

If you're super lucky, it could turn out to be some crappy third-party driver for a piece of external hardware you don't really use anymore, and you can just move that driver out of your `/System/Library/Extensions` folder and be done.

You can opt to have the panic log text displayed on your screen instead of that multi-language graphic by entering the following command (the panic log will still get logged to disk as well):

```
sudo nvram boot-args='debug=0x100'
```